# objective C string Confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I am having code

```
NSString *cellValue1 = [products1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

when i try to print `NSLog(@"cell value is %@",cellValue1);`

in log i am not getting anything,
if i use %s, i am getting some symbols, not the string located in cellValue1.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: %@ is correct for printing an NSString; %s is for a C string (char *).

Comment: Can you add the code which is adding the objects to products1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that `products1` is actually set. It sounds as though it's nil when you send it the `-objectAtIndex:` message.

Comment: No, NSLog display '(null)' when you try to log a nil value as an object.

Comment: The questioner didn't specify that they *weren't* seeing (null) (their interpretation of seeing null may lead them to say they aren't getting anything, since null technically translates to mean nothing.)... Just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks jlehr, above answer solved my problem, problem was products1 was not actually set.

Answer (score 1):

It surely means your string is empty...
Check it with the length method...

Answer (score -1):

***Solution:***

```
NSString *cellValue1 = [products1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell Value is %@", cellValue1]);
```

***Reason:***
NSLog operates with String inputs.  While your statement should work, if there is some/any issue with your original cellValue1 string, your original statement will not catch the issue and assure that that NSLog() is being handed a pure string.  By using the stringWithFormat: syntax you assure that even if your cellValue1 values is null or nil, you will receive your *"cell value is"* comment and possible some hint as to what is being passed into the statement by your cellValue1 string.

**Testing Note:**
If the above doesn't work for you, Test your original string by just using  `NSLog(cellValue1);`.  If this doesn't work it will tell you that your original NSString is not properly pulling your product at indexPath.row values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Nikolai, The sample code was supplied to help the user "Run-Down" a possible solution for the problem by making sure that that he was getting an actual string.  Thanks for the downgrade point!